# How do you make a submit button in HTML5?

Tags: html, input, submit, element, markup

Given [W3C's HTML5 spec for the submit button](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/button.submit.html):

> A button element must have both a start tag and an end tag.

what's an example of a submit button with a start and end tag?

1. `<button type="submit">`
2. `<button type="submit" />`
3. `<button type="submit" ></button>`
4. 2 & 3
5. None of the above

Is the answer the same for other "singleton" tags, like `<input>` or `<img>`?

Comment: "singleton" tags are called void elements in HTML5 specifications.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

```
<button type="submit">Click me</button>
```

[W3C](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-button-element) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/button) has more information.